# How to loop to let the user to reenter if the record is not found in the text file in bash?

Tags: bash, awk

I currently have a text file called `student.txt` and there are some records in the text file.
The format of the records are `StudentID|Name|ContactNumber|EmailAddress` and the records are as follows:

```
21PMR07222|Steven|011-1234567|steven@yahoo.com
21PMR07123|John|012-3456789|john@yahoo.com
21PMR07221|Amy|017-4567890|amy@gmail.com
```

The code below is to check whether the student ID entered by the user exist or not exist in the `student.txt` file:

```
awk -F'|' -v id="$studentID" '
$1 == id { found=1
           printf "Name: %s\nContact Number: %s\nEmail Address: %s\n", $2, $3, $4
         }
END      { if (found==0) {
              printf "The student ID does not exist. Please enter again." 
           }
         }
' < student.txt
```

The user can enter the student ID to search for the student details. How to **loop** to let the user to **reenter** the student ID if the student ID entered by the user does not exist in the text file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following shell script(save this program as a shell script, with appropriate permissions and then run it). Here my file's name is `Input_file` from where `awk` program reads the input.

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
   echo "Please do enter the user id which you want to match from file:"
   read value
   output=$(awk -F'|' -v id="$value" '
      $1 == id { found=1
         printf "Name: %s\nContact Number: %s\nEmail Address: %s\n", $2, $3, $4
      }
   END{
      if (found==0) {
         printf "The student ID does not exist. Please enter again."
      }
   }
'  Input_file)
Invalid='The student ID does not exist. Please enter again.'
   if [[ "$output" == "$Invalid" ]]
   then
        echo "NO match found, so re-asking user to enter the value now..."
   else
        echo "$output"
        exit
   fi
done
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, running an infinite `while` loop in bash, which runs till an exact match is found in Input_file by `awk` program. So basically in an infinite while loop I am running `awk` command(posted by OP in question itself) and then getting its output into a variable and checking if output variable is `The student ID does not exist. Please enter again.` then again it will run the loop and ask user to enter details ELSE it will print `output` value and exit from program.

Comment: Can I know what is the use of `output` variable?

Comment: @StevenThoo, ure I have added detailed explanation in my code now, let me know if you have any questions, cheers. Output variable has awk program's output in it and then I am matching its value to Invalid variable which has The student ID does not exist. Please enter again. in it if this is the case it will re-ask to enter values else it will exit from program.

Comment: I have first entered `21PMR07222`, the details of the student are not showing, instead it prompts me to enter another student ID. I entered `21PMR07123`, the details of the student are displayed, and it exits from the program. (the student ID entered are the IDs shown in the `student.txt` file)

Comment: @StevenThoo, Please do check my edited code, it has worked fine for me. Kindly do refresh your page here and try this code, it has worked fine for me. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: @StevenThoo, when I enter same id see I am getting correct output as: `./script.bash
Please do enter the user id which you want to match from file:
21PMR07222
Name: Steven
Contact Number: 011-1234567
Email Address: steven@yahoo.com
` in my screen.

Comment: @StevenThoo, As an addiotnal check could you please do run `cat -v Input_file` on your file to see if you control M characters in your file? Sometimes if we copy file from windows OS then it may come, let me know what you see, cheers.

Comment: Sorry just now I mislooked some codes so there are errors. After I fixed it, it works well now. But when I entered a student ID which does not exist in the text file, the error message does not appear.

Answer (score 1):

Would you please try the following:

```
awk -F'|' '
NR==FNR {name[$1] = $2; num[$1] = $3; addr[$1] = $4; next}
BEGIN {print "Enter student ID"}
$1 in name {
    printf "Name: %s\nContact Number: %s\nEmail Address: %s\n", name[$1], num[$1], addr[$1]
    next
}
{
     print "The student ID does not exist. Please enter again."
}
' student.txt -
```

It first reads the `student.txt` file then asks the user to input a student ID in STDIN one by one.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

prompt='Enter an ID'
result=1
while (( result != 0 )); do
    IFS= read -p "$prompt: " -r studentID
    prompt='The student ID does not exist. Please enter again'

    awk -F'|' -v id="$studentID" '
        $1 == id {
            printf "Name: %s\nContact Number: %s\nEmail Address: %s\n", $2, $3, $4
            found = 1
            exit
        }
        END { exit !found }
    ' student.txt

    result=$?
done
```